# Ошибки библиотек Keras & ImageAI

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

На картинке виден код (видео с ютуба), там всё ок, но тут что-то всё идёт не так.

Первый скрин - ошибки при компиляции, второй - если запустить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Python 3.7.0, библиотеки все скачаны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно код, который вы взяли из интернета написан под `TensorFlow 1.x`.

Попробуйте установить TensorFlow 1.X и совметимые с ним версии модулей `Keras`, etc.

[Здесь можно посмотреть как запускать код, написанный для `TensorFlow 1.X` на `TensorFlow 2.X`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), но возможно вам для этого понадобится править другие библиотеки, вызывающие `tensorflow`, поэтому проще будет установить `TensorFlow 1.X`.